# Create a full height flex layout with scroll elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to create a flex layout that consists of three columns, each column full height. The thing is, I would like the three div's inside them to always stretch equally from top to bottom, but the last element of outer div's should never be taller than some 40% of the height, it should scroll if it wants to stretch more. I'm not sure if I'm using the correct approach, so any help would be welcome..here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2etg907f/2/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

footer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

main {
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.center-column {
  background-color: lightpink;
  width: 40%;
}

.first-part {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.second-part {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.third-part {
  max-height: 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li>Some link</li>
      <li>Some link</li>
      <li>Some link</li>
      <li>Some link</li>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <main>
    <aside>
      <div class="first-part">
        Some text
      </div>

      <div class="second-part">
        Some text
      </div>

      <div class="third-part">
        Some text
      </div>
    </aside>

    <div class="center-column">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde pariatur possimus eligendi, voluptatem ab id molestiae dolorem obcaecati eaque omnis sit est facere enim tenetur doloremque! Obcaecati magnam consequatur velit.
    </div>

    <aside>
      right column
    </aside>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <ul>
      <li>Some link</li>
      <li>Some link</li>
      <li>Some link</li>
      <li>Some link</li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/52q8bjdo/ ?

Comment: Exactly...thanks! I would accept it as a correct answer, not sure if I can do it in comment

Answer (score 1):

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dhruvil21_04/w2zu68yd/40/)

You were on right path, but `height` on children doesn't just do anything in this scenario without viewport's height, you have to use **viewport height** and subtract the height of header and footer from it.
  `height: calc(100vh - 76px)`. And then for 3 child divs, their height will be       `33.33%`.

Also, using `scroll-y: auto` will only bring scrollbar if the content is more than the height as you can see for 1st div in demo.